# Countermeasure for Drain Flys

Tags: drain, pest-control

A Florida home was saturated with [drain flys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drain_fly).  What is the most effective countermeasure, besides keeping drains filled with water?

Comment: Okay, I'll bite - what is a drain fly? Is it like a fruit fly?

Comment: Wikipedia does a much better job than I can. OP updated.

Answer (score 2):

I've read that pouring oil, such as vegetable oil, into a drain will put a film on top of the water in the trap and that this will dramatically slow the evaporation of the water. When you anticipate that water won't be run through a drain for a long period of time, you could preemptively add oil to that drain.

This might leave an objectionable ring around the inside of a toilet bowl, but for other drains, maybe it's worth a shot.

Comment: I wonder which oil (Canola, Corn, Sunflower, etc) would be the best choice.  Clever idea!

Comment: Propylene glycol if you'll be gone for a while. It's readily available as pool or RV antifreeze and won't go rancid. Possibly raw linseed oil if you want something short term. It's probably the most economical vegetable oil which won't develop a smell.

Comment: light mineral oil won't go rancid.  I don't think glycol will prevent evaporation much as it's miscible in water.

Answer (score 1):

Well you've ruled out the obvious way which is keeping the drains , traps, full of water. Next up would be using drain stoppers. Your home store has all sorts of them. I have used the white rubber stoppers many times when leaving the residence for an extended amount of time. I have also used Glad wrap over the toilet bowels to prevent evaporation of the water in them. I don't think insecticides are good because they could contaminate the water.

Comment: The challenge is that someone has to pour water every month into all drains, especially in the dryer season.  I like the Glad Wrap toilet idea: if you had a photo, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @gatorback  I don't have one handy but it's just Glad wrap stretched over the bowel and down the sides a bit.  Just remember to take it off before using the toilet.

Comment: maybe trap a piece of paper between layers of wrap as a warning.